# jQuery - Getting values of multiple object

Tags: jquery

I've got an object that declares other objects and then I'm looping through a series of inputs. Each of those inputs have a parent div that wraps them in sections so "credit, cash and debt".

```
var paymentObj = {
    credit: {},
    cash: {},
    debt: {}
};

$('.payments input').each(function(){
    var paymentCategory = $('input[class*="filter-section-"]').attr('class').match(/filter-section-(.*)/)[1];
    var paymentName = this.id;
}
```

If I do a **console.log(paymentObj)**. I get values like:

```
Object { credit={visa=true, mastercard=false, amex=true}}, cash={}, debt={mastercard=true, amex=false}}
```

How would I get the values of just the credit object? I'm really looking to return if something is set to true in the credit object as comma delimited. **visa, amex**

I learn best by code samples so please include code samples. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) on the `paymentObj.credit` object once the value is populated to get the comma delimited string

```
var credits = $.map(paymentObj.credit, function(a, b){
    return a ? b : undefined;
}).join(',')
console.log(credits)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LX4q9/)

Answer (score 0):

Just so the non-jquery specific way is here:

```
var values = [];
for(var key in paymentObj.credit) {
    if(paymentObj.credit.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(paymentObj.credit[key]) {
            values.push(key);
        }
    }
}

console.log(values.join(','));
```

Or depending on your browser support requirement, you may be able to drop the `hasOwnProperty`:

```
var values = [];
for(var key in paymentObj.credit) {
    if(paymentObj.credit[key]) {
        values.push(key);
    }
}

console.log(values.join(','));
```